# execution is not getting started from main() in python unittest (IDE : Eclipse + PyDev)

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev, python-unittest

Execution is not getting started from main() in python unittest (IDE : Eclipse + PyDev)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("here")
    testRunner = xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output="D:\\")
    unittest.main(testRunner)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `__main__` executed you need to run as a regular file... running as unit-test is for PyDev itself to do the test collection (so, in that case it'd run the tests themselves without running the main entry point).